# How to retrieve data from JButton?

Tags: java, swing, components, jbutton

I'm looking to create `JButton` controls from a loop then use an event handler to pull relevant information and manipulate that further using SQL commands.

However I cannot access the component name or component text fields of the created button objects.

```
try {
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Products";
    ResultSet rs = GetDB.AccessDatabse(SQL);

    while(rs.next()){
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        btn.setName(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        System.out.println(btn.getName()); 
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn);
                    }
    }   
 catch (SQLException ex) {System.out.println("GUI Creation Error");}    
}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        System.out.println(this.getName()); 
    }
```

I would expect the button name to be set to the SQL Query result, but when attempting to print the result it displays `"frame0"` for each button.

The Text area of each button is working

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: @Alan Robinson just a quick tipp: when dealing with this keyword, please include the class so we can see the this-context immediately;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `getName()` on `this`, which is not the button, it is your this-context which is your `JFrame`.

You need to parse the source of the `ActionEvent`.

Here I made some quick code which could do what you want:

```
actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
  if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
    //Casting here is safe after the if condition
    JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
    System.out.println(b.getText());
  } else {
    System.out.println("Something other than a JButton was clicked");
  }
}
```

What I do: I check if the action source is a `JButton` and then cast it to a new local variable and then get the text of this.

Comment: I thought `frame0` seemed odd for a moment as I was editing the question, but it slipped my mind! Nicely spotted.

Comment: I also needed to look twice:)